listings and Greek characters with punctuation
I have to write a document that requires inside an lstlisting environment to have Greek letters, but not just αβγ... ΑΒΓ... on top of them I need their versions with punctuation like ά... Ά... also I do compile with pdflatex due to other packages needed.
I did found a way for the no punctuation characters on this answer from a couple years ago, it works, but anything I tried to extend it with punctuation characters did not work.
I searched for other ways too but no luck as well (like changing parameters on the style of listings in general to make it utf8 and something with math).
The following code is what I want to make work, the present packages must stay.
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
aαά
\end{lstlisting}
\lstinline{aαά}
\end{document}

The result I expect to achieve is the following (inside the document of course):
aαά
aαά

So far I have managed staff like the following which is kinda expected from what I understand due to how listings work.
LaTeX Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence (�\expandafter).

Note: ά is one character with punctuation, but the rest work similarly (and then some don't) and I would expect a solution that covers Greek characters (modern at least) in general and not just a specific workaround.

Welcome to tex.sx.  You need to be using a utf-8-aware engine (xelatex or lualatex) and preferably a font with the precomposed letters.  I can't help with letters that need
additional diacritics, but hope someone else can.

Welcome! If you can use minted instead of listings, it will work fine, even with pdflatex (since processing of the code is taken over by python).

@barbarabeeton I did try with both xelatex and luatex, and with \usepackage[LGR]{fontenc} for example, but still I wasn't able to use the input in lstlisting (aαά as test) with the same error as the one in question.

@nplatis I did use minted before and it worked effortlessly, but it requires Python during compilation for the pygmentize tool to be called, which the authorities prefer to avoid, in order to keep external dependencies low to none.

You can use literate. Here's a sample, you need to complete the alphabet set, using the standard transliteration scheme that you find in the documentation of the cbfonts:

Here are the entries for lower/upper case alphabet and from accent symbols oxia and dialytika. Note the peculiar way to insert the sigma and the final sigma.
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
%  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=flexible,
  literate=%
    {α}{{\textgreek{a}}}1%
    {ά}{{\textgreek{'a}}}1%
    {β}{{\textgreek{b}}}1%
    {γ}{{\textgreek{g}}}1%
    {δ}{{\textgreek{d}}}1%
    {ε}{{\textgreek{e}}}1%
    {έ}{{\textgreek{'e}}}1%
    {ζ}{{\textgreek{z}}}1%
    {η}{{\textgreek{h}}}1%
    {ή}{{\textgreek{'h}}}1%
    {θ}{{\textgreek{j}}}1%
    {ι}{{\textgreek{i}}}1%
    {ί}{{\textgreek{'i}}}1%
    {ϊ}{{\textgreek{"i}}}1%
    {ΐ}{{\textgreek{'"i}}}1%
    {κ}{{\textgreek{k}}}1%
    {λ}{{\textgreek{l}}}1%
    {μ}{{\textgreek{m}}}1%
    {ν}{{\textgreek{n}}}1%
    {ξ}{{\textgreek{x}}}1%
    {ο}{{\textgreek{o}}}1%
    {ό}{{\textgreek{'o}}}1%
    {π}{{\textgreek{p}}}1%
    {ρ}{{\textgreek{r}}}1%
    {σ}{{\textgreek{sv}}}1%
    {ς}{{\textgreek{c}}}1%
    {τ}{{\textgreek{t}}}1%
    {υ}{{\textgreek{u}}}1%
    {ύ}{{\textgreek{'u}}}1%
    {ϋ}{{\textgreek{"u}}}1%
    {ΰ}{{\textgreek{'"u}}}1%
    {φ}{{\textgreek{f}}}1%
    {χ}{{\textgreek{q}}}1%
    {ψ}{{\textgreek{y}}}1%
    {ω}{{\textgreek{w}}}1%
    {ώ}{{\textgreek{'w}}}1%
    {Α}{{\textgreek{A}}}1%
    {Β}{{\textgreek{B}}}1%
    {Γ}{{\textgreek{G}}}1%
    {Δ}{{\textgreek{D}}}1%
    {Ε}{{\textgreek{E}}}1%
    {Ζ}{{\textgreek{Z}}}1%
    {Η}{{\textgreek{H}}}1%
    {Θ}{{\textgreek{J}}}1%
    {Ι}{{\textgreek{I}}}1%
    {Κ}{{\textgreek{K}}}1%
    {Λ}{{\textgreek{L}}}1%
    {Μ}{{\textgreek{M}}}1%
    {Ν}{{\textgreek{N}}}1%
    {Ξ}{{\textgreek{X}}}1%
    {Ο}{{\textgreek{O}}}1%
    {Π}{{\textgreek{P}}}1%
    {Ρ}{{\textgreek{R}}}1%
    {Σ}{{\textgreek{S}}}1%
    {Τ}{{\textgreek{T}}}1%
    {Υ}{{\textgreek{U}}}1%
    {Φ}{{\textgreek{F}}}1%
    {Χ}{{\textgreek{Q}}}1%
    {Ψ}{{\textgreek{Y}}}1%
    {Ω}{{\textgreek{W}}}1%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
aαάβγσςβ
\end{lstlisting}

\lstinline{aαά}

\end{document}

Don't forget the braces around \textgreek{<letter>}.


Appending the babel-greek website in which other accent symbols and punctuation can be found to complete the skeleton. Could not find it myself earlier, so the cbfonts mention helped, thank you. Essentially we are making a map (similar to the other answer I mentioned in the question), but is there any less manual way? This one works for my needs after I complete the skeleton, but in case another language is needed for example Italian, then you have to extend the map with the necessary entries like é etc.

@ioannis-kokkalis You might want to switch to minted.
